# Is there a way to delete a file as a VSTS task after a deploy task?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am implementing a feature where the website shows 'Maintenance Mode' page when a Azure Pipeline is being deployed. For this, I am deploying a file called app_offline.htm that is placed at the root of the IIS web directory. This works perfectly since what I am doing is copying a file from artifacts directory to the deployment server.

But I am unable to delete/rename the deployed file once the deployment is complete. Is there a way to do so? I am looking ideally to rename it to app_online.htm so the website is enabled again.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build-in [Delete Files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/delete-files?view=azure-devops) is manage to delete files or folders from the **agent working directory**.

According to your description, seems `app_offline.htm` was already on the deployment server during the deployment and after the deployment finished.

You need to use some 3-rd part extension such as  [Delete Remote File or Folder](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=automagically.DeleteRemoteFolderFile&ssr=false#overview), you could also write your own powershell script and run with some commands to handle this.

Besides, you could also give a try with this task-- [Manage remote IIS](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=automagically.ManageRemoteIIS) in your scenario, it provide a way to Create/configure/delete website in IIS server.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @PatrickLu-MSFT. For the remote delete tasks, how can I provide the username and password credentials without plain text?

Comment: Hi @J.Doe Sorry for this. It's not a build-in Microsoft task. We could not provide any way of it.  It's just a choice to handle your problem. If that not meet your needs, suggest you use powershell task or write your own task. We provide  secret variable to hide your password info with using own task.

Comment: Yes it did! Sorry about that. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a powershell task at the end of the deployment. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops

Use the rename-item command (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-7)