# Delete files uploaded via PublishBuildArtifacts@1 in AzDevops

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I can't find a way to delete files/folders uploaded via PublishBuildArtifacts@1 in AzDevops.

can we do it via cmdLIne task or script?

I can delete all files uploaded in the agent but not that get published.

It gets uploaded to the file container Upload 'C:\Data\Agent_work\2329\a\testr.json' to the file container: #/232343434/test

Comment: Hi @ElonMusk, have you tried the suggestions below to delete the build that published the artifact? There are several ways can delete the build, manually delete, via retention policies, using REST API, etc...

Answer (score 0):

The build-in [Delete Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/delete-files?view=azure-devops) task is manage to delete files or folders from the **agent working directory**.

According to your description, seems `/232343434/test` was already on the deployment server during the deployment and after the deployment finished.

You could use a 3rd party extension such as [Delete Remote File or Folder](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=automagically.DeleteRemoteFolderFile&ssr=false#overview), or you could write your own script that connects to the server and execute some commands to remove what you need

References:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/61200324/4317508
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/delete-files-v1?view=azure-pipelines&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops
- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=automagically.DeleteRemoteFolderFile&ssr=false#overview

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you want to delete the artifact published to Azure Pipelines (Container). If I understand correctly, you need to **delete the build that published the artifact**. Pipeline artifact is associated with each build. To delete the build, you can refer to the followings:

1. Manually delete builds

   [image]
2. Set retention policies for builds

   [Retention policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/retention?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) let you set how long to keep runs, releases, and tests stored in the system. Go to Project Settings -> Settings (under Pipeline tab).
   [image]
3. Using REST API [Builds - Delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/delete?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1).

```
DELETE https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}?api-version=7.1-preview.7
```